# How to apply .each() only for certain parents?

Tags: jquery

```
$("table").each(function(){
//Code goes here
}
```

I want use this(above code ) for  whose parents class attribute "featured". so from below example I want include only 1) ex.
ex:

1)

```
<div class="featured">
<table>
</table>
</div>
```

2)

```
<div class="Nonfeatured">
<table>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$(".featured > table").each(function(){
    //Code goes here
}
```

Comment: But if that direct descendant operator is not needed, will `".featured table"` be faster to run? EDIT: nope totally wrong! http://jsperf.com/jq-direct-child-or-any-child

Comment: No, direct child will definitely be faster, it can reduce the search tree a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want

```
$(".featured table").each(function(){
    //Code goes here
}
```

...which says, "for each `table` element that is a descendant of an element with class "featured", run this function."

Or if you want it only for *direct children* of those elements:

```
$(".featured > table").each(function(){
    //Code goes here
}
```

...which says, "for each `table` element that is an *immediate child* of an element with class "featured", run this function."

More:

- [Descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)
- [Child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".featured table").each(function(){
 //Code goes here
}
```